# How should I structure/separate abstract model classes in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

I am building an abstract class `Log` that will have two subclasses, `InfoLog` and `ErrorLog`.

My question is whether it is best practice to have all of these classes and their definitions in the *same* file (Log.cs), or if they should be split up into one file for each class? Or, if there is no clear-cut best practice, what factors should I consider when deciding if I'll divide them into different files?

Below is my current *Log.cs* file.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public abstract class Log {
    public string LogType;
    public string Message;
    public string ServiceName;
    public string GetJson() {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, 
                                            Formatting.Indented,
                                            new JsonSerializerSettings{ NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});
    }
}


public class ErrorLog : Log {
    public Logger.ErrorCode ErrorCode;
    private string StackTrace;
    public ErrorLog(Logger.ErrorCode errorCode, 
                    string serviceName, 
                    string message, 
                    string stackTrace=null) 
    {
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        this.ServiceName = serviceName;
        this.Message = message;
        this.StackTrace = stackTrace;
        this.LogType = "ERROR";
    }

    public string GetStackTrace(){
        return this.StackTrace;
    }
    public void SetStackTrace(string trace) {
        this.StackTrace = trace;
    }
}


public class InfoLog : Log {
    public InfoLog(string serviceName, string message) {
        this.ServiceName = serviceName;
        this.Message = message;
        this.LogType = "INFO";
    }
}
```

Comment: Each type should be in a separate file.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Why?

Comment: Coding style questions are off-topic on SO as they are completely opinion-based. Pick a style guide you like (you can start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions
 and add whatever you feel necessary or find another one)

Comment: Note that the marked duplicate has dissenting answers, so take it more to learn the pros/cons rather than a de facto answer.